# Is there any way to use the data property inside data same data object in vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm beginner in Vue js as well frontend framework. Recently I learn about vue js. So I have a tiny task in vue js.Simple add user and display all the users which is added by me. So here is my code.

```
<div id="todo">
    <b-card class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <b-row>
        <b-col md="4">
          <b-input v-model="firstName" placeholder="Firstname"></b-input>
        </b-col>
        <b-col md="4">
          <b-input v-model="lastName" placeholder="Lastname"></b-input>
        </b-col>
        <b-col md="2">
          <b-btn class="btn btn-success" @click="addUser">Add User</b-btn>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-card>
    <table>
      <caption>Users</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Index</th>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(u, index) in users" :key="index">
          <td>{{u.uid}}</td>
          <td>{{u.firstname}}</td>
          <td>{{u.lastname}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<script>
export default {
  name: "todo",
  data() {
    return {
      users: [{ id: **this.uid**, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" }],
      **uid**: 1,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addUser() {
      let newUser = {
        id: this.id + 1,
        firstname: this.firstName,
        lastname: this.lastName
      };
      this.users.push(newUser);
      (this.firstName = ""), (this.lastName = "");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

> Now, My question is can I use uid in my users array in data object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in your data like this :

```
<script>
const uid = 1;

export default{
    data(){
       return {
          id : uid
       }

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can by running your code in the **created** method as follows

```
{
   created () {
      let firstUser = { id: this.uid, firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe" }
      this.users.push(firstUser)
   },
   data () {
      users: [],
      uid: 1
   }
}
```